# "The specified module can not be found" in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I just tried to copy my entire web application to a new instance of Visual Studio 2008 on another (virtual) machine.

It builds just fine, but when I try to run the applicaton I just get the message "The specified module could not be found".

Does anyone have an idea how I can find out which module this message refers to? Because there are quite a lot, and as far as I can see they're all installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you delete all the temporary ASP.Net files for your project and then do a rebuild. This will ensure all the new code is recompilled and no old references remain.

Sometime simply building the solution doesn't work and you need to rebuild instead to force it to either show you the real error or get the references correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your project uses COM and an interop assembly, you'll be able to build (because the assembly is there), but raise a runtime exception if the COM server is not registered on the new machine.